# Can FeynCalc be used for Heavy quark effective field?

Tags: feyncalc

I start to learn [FeynCalc](https://feyncalc.github.io/). I want to use it for Heavy quark field theory. For example, extract the vertices from Eq.(34) from paper [1901.10339](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.10319). Since I am not good at FeynCalc, so I want to know whether it can be used to Heavy quark field theory. If yes, which sources can I use? Thank you.